# How can pickup window class of non active/visible window?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, findwindow

I need obtain a list of a class of all windows in order to pickup window handle of a hidden non visible child window.
Using spy++  I can find the windows and see the windows not have setup a window name/caption, only a class and appear appear like this:

```
      HwndWrapper[APPname.exe;;10c71dcc-1a19-4fdf-82f0-57195a824939]
      HwndWrapper[APPname.exe;;3ce85673-ce1f-460f-b2c6-4d3c8ea30b6b]
```

The question is how I can search in all windows and obtain the class programmatically?
There is some way to use this string:
HwndWrapper[APPname.exe;;

That string is always is the same, can be used to list all windows class and then extract what I need (the window handle)

Basically I want pickup the window handle from all windows contain on the classname   HwndWrapper[APPname.exe;;1    and the window title is empty or null.

Then with that i can pickup the handle

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    public IntPtr GetHandleWindow(string classname)
    {
        return FindWindow(classname, null);
    }


        windowHandle = GetHandleWindow("HwndWrapper[APPname.exe;;10c71dcc-1a19-4fdf-82f0-57195a824939]");
```